# Struts 1.2, passing parameters from forms

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, struts-1

So recently I've started working on a big old application in the company I'm currently working. It is written in Spring and is using struts 1.2 as a controller - a technology that I'm not exactly familiar with. My task was to add multiple accepting option - there is a option for accepting a single invoice. Since I do not know how exactly struts work (and believe me the architecture this app is complete spaghetti) I want to use this single accepting action to make multi acceptations - pass the id to the method, and if there is more than one id in the request loop through all of them and go through the accepting process (which is also quite long and quite unreadable) for each of the id.

The problem is - it doesn't seem that the form is passing the id's to the url - in the method i retrieve an array of Id's from the request url. Is there a way in struts to pass parameters through url?

It looks more&less like this:

**The form:**

```
<html:form action="/invoice_processing" method="get" styleClass="form">
   <c:if test="${not empty invoices_list_with_dynamic_checkboxes}">             
      <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/invoices/dynamic_invoices_list_with_checkboxes" flush="true"/>
   </c:if>
</html:form>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action path="/invoice_processing"
   type="pl.blah.blah.InvoiceProcessor"
   name="invoice_processing_form" scope="session" validate="false">
   <forward name="executeTask" path="/i_do_not_matter.do" />
</action>
```

**Edit - adding table and the method "invoices_list_with_dynamic_checkboxes"**

```
<div class="table">
    <table class="table_list_highlight">
        <thead>
            <tr>    

                <th rowspan="2">I do not matter ID</th>
                <th rowspan="2">I do not matter</th>
                <th rowspan="2">I do not matter</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Check the checkbox</th>

            </tr>

        </thead>    
        <c:forEach var="singleInvoice" items="${invoicesThatAreDeclaredBeforeAndWork}">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2"><c:out value="${singleInvoice.invoice.amount}"/></td>
                    <td rowspan="2"><c:out value="${singleInvoice.invoice.date}"/></td>         
                    <td rowspan="2"><c:out value="${singleInvoice.invoice.whatever}"/></td>         
                    <td rowspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" value='${singleInvoice.invoice.id}'></td>

                </tr>           
            </tbody>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
```

**The Method that it goes to (note: ActionContext is self made class that does not implement any interface of extend any context class - although it retrieves the request url via getRequest() - altho it provides something like invoiceProcessing.do)**

```
protected void execute(ActionContext actionContext) throws Exception {

    HttpServletRequest request = actionContext.getRequest();
    List<String> listOfIdString= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer>listOfIdInt= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    InvoiceEditionForm forma = (CFakturaEdycjaForm) actionContext.getForm();
    String[] idArray = request.getParameterValues("checkboxGroup");

    if(idArray != null && idArray.length > 0) {

        listOfIdString = Arrays.asList(idArray);

        for(String currentId: listOfIdString) {

            listOfIdInt.add(Integer.parseInt(currentId));

        }

        for(Integer currentId: listaIdFakturaInt) {

            Invoice invoice = invoiceLogic.findInvoiceById(currentId);

            (Acceptance process goes here)

        }

}
```

All of those names are renamed in english - I can't copy paste all of this code because it is really long and basically has stuff that works and is not a problem. The problem lies in retrieving the id that are submitted by the form itself.

Comment: post the `dynamic_invoices_list_with_checkboxes` page and action method too.

Comment: Added the method and the list!

Comment: I didn't find any of your parameter named `id` as you mentioned `String[] idArray = request.getParameterValues("id");` instead you're having values in `checkboxGroup` in your form.

Comment: You should try with `String[] idArray = request.getParameterValues("checkboxGroup");` in your action.

Comment: A small mistake when rewriting it - the whole app is written in Polish so i do not want to differentiate from that, and certainly i do not want to post code in polish ;) I will edit this though!

Comment: Do you getting any error in java / browser console?